# HTTPURLConnection - Content-Integrity

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, put

I'm doing the file uploading with the `HttpUrlConnection` class.

```
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Trailer", "Content-Integrity");              
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) (getSourceSize()-pos));

while ((bytes = in.read(block, 0, DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)) > 0) {
        out.write(block, 0, bytes);
}
```

And after that I need to send the Content-Integrity header like:
*Content-Integrity:
sha-256:bdcf7f645fd53dd3b3763f59376134ff58cc337247c978bdd178b6ccdfbff19f*

How can I do this?

Comment: My answer presumed you were trying to do something different. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851645/how-do-i-send-http-trailers-footers-in-a-chunked-response-from-within-a-java-ser

Answer (score 0):

Generally HTTP/TCP will already ensure that the data was reassembled correctly, if you are worried about data security than SSL (or other for of encryption) will be better.